# ReactJS: get data from api and map data

Tags: reactjs

I am learning ReactJS. In my program, I am making an API call and later mapping it.
The data which is fetched by API call is like,
data = [{"uid":"1", "title":"hello"},{"uid":"2", "title":"World"}]

```
import ImporterAPI from '../api';
const API = new ImporterAPI();

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: ''
  }}

  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({ data: API.getData()}, () => {
      console.log("data fetched");
      var mapData = []
      this.state.data.map( (object, i) => {
        mapData.push(<p key={i}>{object}</p>)
      })
  }) 
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="home">
        {this.mapData}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And my API file,

```
import axios from 'axios';
class API {
  getData = () => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8005/data')
    .then(function (response) {
      if (response.status === 200 && response != null) {
        var data = response.data;
        console.log(data)
        return data
      } else {
        console.log('problem');
      }
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
```

My console.log is printing the data from API call and then I'm returning the data. Where in home component data is assigned using setState. But there is no data storing into this.state.data. It always remains undefined and I got error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined".

Please guide me. How should I print API call data & I would also like to know if this program is good or bad in terms of performance for making API calls or any other better way to improve performance. Thanks.

I would appreciate help.

Comment: You missed the `return` before `axios`. Just add `return` in front of `axios` like this `return axios` , it will work.

Comment: I think the response is a JSON object and so the map function will not work. Can you please post your sample response data here?

Comment: @kumark ... my console print response data -> (2) 
[ 0:{"uid":"1", "title":"hello"}
 1: {"uid":"2", "title":"World"}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're two problems in your code.

First, `API.getData()` is an async function. It means when you call `API.getData()`, the data is not return intermediately (think like it takes few milliseconds to get the data). You should `setState` after you fetched the data.

Secondly, you should send render logic in `render` function.

It should look like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ImporterAPI from '../api'
const API = new ImporterAPI()

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      data: []
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    API.getData().then(response => {
      console.log('Data fetched', response)
      this.setState({
        data: response
      })
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="home">
        {this.state.data.map((object, index) => (
          <p key={index}>{object}</p>
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

As @Askiron answer, you also should `return axios....` in your API function.

Edit 2: Here's the better API, which return data in error case, so you don't get `this.state.data is not a function`:

```
import axios from 'axios'

class API {
  getData = () => {
    return axios
      .get('http://localhost:8005/data')
      .then(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 200 && response != null) {
          var data = response.data
          return data
        } else {
          throw new Error('Empty data')
        }
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error)
        return [] // Return empty array in case error response.
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying :) .... After following your steps I'm getting this error "TypeError: this.state.data.map is not a function" and in the API component console.log is printing data twice ...similarly console.log is printing data twice in Home component.

Comment: Sorry. You should init your data state to empty array at first. I edited my code. Check it out!

Comment: And in the API, you should return data in error cases. Think `API.getData()` is like a function, get input and return output. In case of error, you seem not return any data. I will update my answer to hope you can understand more, can resolve all your problems.

Comment: And your console print data twice, is because one print in `API.getData()`, one print in your React Component when you fetch data. So I delete the `console.log` in `API.getData()`.

Comment: I'm getting same error at Home.render ... "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Comment: Are you sure your `response.data` is an array? If you want to check, print the `this.state.data` before the `return` in `render()` function. This error means your `this.state.data` is undefined, so the `this.state.data` doesn't have `map` function in its property.

Comment: Hi, The data is an array. I have checked with Array.isArray(data). But when I run the console.log inside render to check the data (this.state.data). The output comes as Undefined. Even though setState is done.

Comment: Does the console print any thing about `response` (`console.log('Data fetched', response)`). As the warning content, your `data` is set to `undefined`. It means maybe your API return wrong content of data. I can't make any further help about this. 

On the other hand, when I code the example for you, my editor warns me "componentWillMount is deprecated...", can you change it to `componentDidMount` just for testing purpose?

Comment: Yes I have changed to componentDidMount(). "console.log('Data fetched', response))" is printing the data. But data becomes undefined when console.log(this.state.data) runs inside render(). Is it working for you?

Comment: I don't actual run the code, but I'm pretty sure the code above works correctly. Please check with separated code to be sure the component does not affect by any other sources. Just `console.log` and think about the flow of your code. Hope you can fix this soon.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183845/discussion-between-miraihanabi-and-haru53).

Answer (score 3):

Do you really need another class for getting api data? Not required

Also componentWillMount method is deprecated so I would recommend you to move your axios code to componentDidMount method within the class.

Also initialize the data with empty array instead of string. And set the api response data to state i.e., data

Do map directly in render and display data.

Use arrow function in axios .then and .catch like I did in the below code otherwise this won’t be available to access state or props. You need to bind every .then and .catch otherwise

Your code can be simplified something like below

```
     class Home extends Component {
         constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
               data: []
            }
         }

      componentDidMount() {
          axios.get('http://localhost:8005/data')
            .then(response => {
                if (response.status === 200 && response != null) {
                  this.setState({
                       data: response.data
                  });
           } else {
             console.log('problem');
           }
      })
      .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
      });
    }

    render() {
       const { data } = this.state;
       return (
          <div className="home">
            {Array.isArray(data) && data.map(object => (
                 <p key={object.uid}>{object.title}</p>
             ))}
          </div>
        )
    }
  }
```

Comment: :) I am getting this error "TypeError: data.map is not a function"

Comment: I updated my answer. Please give a try now. But Make sure the api returns the data i.e., console.log(response.data); should print array of objects in axios success response

Comment: I'm getting "http://localhost:8005/data" 404 not found and another error request failed. But before this error I'm getting Map error "Uncaught TypeError: data.map is not a function".

Comment: That means the api url is incorrect. Check your backend api path. If you provide right path to axios.get then the code would work as expected

Comment: I fixed it and got .... "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: res.json is not a function"

Comment: Ok remove res.json it should be fine now. Check my updated answer