# react-dom.development.js:55 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm super confused here, I'm trying to follow this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53358155/reactjs-get-data-from-api-and-map-data) yet keep getting the error objects aren't valid as a react child. Or property is undefined.

The api response should be something like `[{id:1, name: hugo}, {id:2, name:sally}]`

What is causing these errors, why isn't the Component will mount lifecyle component changing state onload.

And why if I try to console.log the results of this do i get undefined.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Form } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { api31Call } from '../helpers';
import ItemLister from './ItemLister';

export default class PulseInputForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            data: [],
        }
    }

    fetchData = () => {
      api31Call('GET', '/projects')
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          loading: false,
          data: data
        })
      })
    }

    componentWillMount() {
      this.setState({loading: true})
      this.fetchData()
      }

    render() {          
      return(
      <div>
      {this.state.data.map((object, index) => (
          <p key={index}>{object}</p>
        ))}
       </div>
      )  
      }
}
```

Comment: I'm aware i'm missing a loading state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not render object. You can show only text.

```
{this.state.data.map((object, index) => (
          <p key={index}>{object}</p>
        ))}
       </div>
      )
```

The `object` in your code means each item of array like `{id:1, name: hugo}`

So, I think `name` is what you want to show. Please use `object.name` to show each name

And you should not use index in `key`. It is better to use primary key in your data like `id`

#### change like this

```
{this.state.data.map((object) => (
          <p key={object.id}>{object.name}</p>
        ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to render object field not object.

```
{this.state.data.map((object, index) => (
          <p key={index}>{object.name}</p>
        ))}
```